# IF ELSE CONDTION IN EXCEL

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

How to write a function to calculate

if A = VARCHAR or CHAR then compare B value with E value, if same then 'Match' else 'Not Match'.

if A = NUMERIC then compare B value with F value and C value with G value, if same then 'Match' else 'Not Match'

Other than VARCHAR/CHAR/NUMERIC then 'Blank'

*NULL treat it as 0

```
A       B   C     D        E F   G    H 
VARCHAR 8   0     VARCHAR  8 0   0    Match 
CHAR    8   0     CHAR     8 0   0    Match 
NUMERIC 19  2     NUMERIC  9 19  2    Match 
NUMERIC 1   NULL  NUMEIC   5 1   0    Match 
NUMERIC 1   1     NUMERC   5 1   0    Not Match 
DATE    1   1     DATE     8 23  3    Blank
```

Here is the code, how to change NULL value to 0 ?

```
=IF(OR(A1="VARCHAR",A1="CHAR"),IF(B1=E1,"MATCH","NOT MATCH"),IF(A1="NUMERIC",IF(AND(B1=F1,C1=G1),"MATCH","NOT MATCH"),"Blank"))
```

Comment: Can the columns B, F, C and G contain something else than `NULL` or numbers?

Comment: only column C will have NULL

Comment: Wait, does that mean that B, F and G will _always_ contain numbers?

Comment: Yes..................

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transform the Null to a zero with a nested IF statement.

=if(cell="Null",0,cell)

Here transforming values in column C as well as in in column G:

```
=IF(OR(A1="VARCHAR",A1="CHAR"),IF(B1=E1,"MATCH","NOT MATCH"),IF(A1="NUMERIC",IF(AND(B1=F1,IF(C1="Null",0,C1)=IF(G1="Null",0,G1)),"MATCH","NOT MATCH"),"Blank"))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this slightly shorter formula as well:

```
=IF(OR(A4={"VARCHAR","CHAR"}),IF(B4=E4,"MATCH","NOT MATCH"),IF(A4="NUMERIC",IF(AND(B4=F4,IFERROR(1*C4,0)=G4),"MATCH","NOT MATCH"),"Blank"))
```

`OR(A4={"VARCHAR","CHAR"})` is a shorter way to write `OR(A1="VARCHAR",A1="CHAR")`;

`IFERROR(1*C4,0)` is for the `NULL` part. `1*C4` returns an error only when C4 is not a number, and that's when C4 is `NULL`. If that's an error, then use `0` instead.